# Accessing my malloc'd 2d array with [x][y]

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm updating a class to use member variable instead of #defines to define the bounds of a 2d array. It used to look like:

```
#define kWidth 3
#define kHeight 100
NSUInteger fields[kWidth][kHeight];
```

Now kWidth and kHeight are iVars. I switched to malloc convention, because I see no other choice as the bounds can now change. The problem is I cannot access the array using two [] ([][]). See my inline comments. I am sure I've malloc'd correctly. I've done this many times before, and under iOS. Why can't I access this way?

> ```
> self.kFieldsHeight = 100;
> self.kFieldsWidth = 3;
> NSUInteger** fields = (NSUInteger**)malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger) * self.kFieldsHeight * self.kFieldsWidth);
> memset(fields, 0xFF,  self.kFieldsWidth * self.kFieldsHeight * sizeof(NSUInteger));
>
> //// Now with LLDB I can examine the array in one dimension
> // p fields[0]      // 0xFFFFFFFF
> // p fields[299]    // 0xFFFFFFFF
> // p fields[300]    // 0xGARBAGE
>
> //// THIS fails with "error: Couldn't dematerialize struct : Couldn't read a composite type from the target: gdb remote returned an
> ```
>
> error: E08"
>       // p fields[0][0]
>
> ```
> // Thus this fails in my code
> NSUInteger i = fields[0][0];
> ```

What's the deal?

Edit: (more detail)
I've also tried mallocing like this:

```
fields = (NSUInteger**)malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger*) * self.kFieldsHeight);
if(fields){
    for(int i = 0; i < self.kFieldsHeight; i++){
        fields[i] = (NSUInteger*)malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger) * self.kFieldsWidth);
    }
}
```

Edit: (even more detail). I swapped the width and height with the same results:

```
fields = (NSUInteger**)malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger*) * self.kFieldsWidth);
if(fields){
    for(int i = 0; i < self.kFieldsWidth; i++){
        fields[i] = (NSUInteger*)malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger) * self.kFieldsHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've also tried mallocing this way:

Comment: did you consider mallocating one large, continuous chunk of type `NSUInteger *` and of size `sizeof(NSUInteger) * width * height`, then accessing it like `item = pointer[width * row + column]`?

Comment: Also, pretty please, for the love of God, **do not cast the return value of malloc()!** It returns `void *` which is compatible with any data pointer type.

Comment: Okay, point taken about casting. 

About your way to read. That's fine if it works, however the rest of the class is already written and functioning fine so I'd rather not have to go change anything if I don't need to. This is totally valid syntax and should work unless I've done something wrong (which I'm not seeing).

Comment: of course it is, it just decreases readability. By the way, so did you try the one-chunk approach with *correct indexing?*

Comment: swapping width and height has no point, width and height is only for programmers point of view. Btw could you copy paste the error message you get? Unless you did and I cannot see it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fields = (NSUInteger**)malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger*) * self.kFieldsWidth);
if(fields){
    for(int i = 0; i < self.kFieldsWidth; i++){
        fields+i = (NSUInteger*)malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger) * self.kFieldsHeight);
    }
}
```

no real reason for doing it this way, just another way of saying a[i] is a+i
I am using my C knowledge here and not objective C hope I can help

Comment: I actually just update my post to share that I've tried that way of mallocing too. (see the update). Same results. I can examine the array using one dimension, but not two.

Comment: edited my post with something new. Try it. I'm not really optimistic about it but give it a shot

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I went ahead and re-implemented the existing class using single indexing. Deadlines.....

Comment: macrian, thanks for your effort. 
At this point I went ahead and re-implemented the existing class code using single indexing because it works, although I prefer double. Must move forward.

I don't think there was an issue with actually allocating and setting because (with most of the techniques in this thread) my class works just fine (like before changing the array declaration) with single indexing. I just could not access it with the [][] syntax. 

However try the code with bool**. It works. Not with char**, not with NSUInteger**. Maybe that will ring a bell.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
NSUInteger **fields = malloc(self.kFieldsHeight * sizeof(NSUInteger*));
for (int i = 0; i < self.kFieldsHeight; i++) {
     fields[i] = malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger) * self.kFieldsWidth);
     memset(fields, 0xFF,  self.kFieldsWidth * sizeof(NSUInteger));
}
```

But this is not the way most people do the job. Most developers use a big array instead of a 2d array and try to index it themselves. Like this:

```
NSUInteger *fields = malloc(self.kFieldsHeight * self.kFieldsHeight *  sizeof(NSUInteger));
fields[h * width + w] = pixel_value;
```

Comment: Fixed... everything. Your answer is a nice proof of why one should use `sizeof(*pointer)` instead of `sizeof(type)` when mallocating - this code would have invoked a very nice undefined behavior on 32-bit platforms (where `sizeof(NSUInteger) != sizeof(NSUInteger *)`).

Comment: I reverted your edit. I liked my code more. There were a mistake in second part which is fixed.

Comment: why do most developpers do that? I don't do that, I find it much easier using 2D arrays.....

Comment: @HCHogan It's not a coincidence that there's an edit functionality on StackOverflow. This answer was/is bad, and its author stubbornly fights for all the bad practices he follows and the mistakes he made. I wanted to improve the answer in order to make it as high-quality as possible, but the author did not accept that and reverted it to the original, broken one, so I downvoted it and flagged as low quality, that it is. That's all.

Comment: I agree with H2CO3 if you have wrong code accept the edit, otherwise accept the downvote. I was downvoted because I asked a question with wrong code......

Comment: Let's try to keep the comments constructive and to a minimum, please.

Comment: @Tim Post, No I think this is constructive. H2CO3, you can not edit a post with 100 characters and change 64 characters!!! You can add a comment. You changed the whole code, while only one * operator was extra, in the second part, which was a suggestion not an answer! I do think you did the wrong thing. Don't care about your downvote either.

Comment: @macrian, indeed it's much easier to work with image when it's only one array. For instance, if you want increase all values, you can work with only one pointer. This is pretty much standard in all image manipulation libraries (e.g OpenCV, ImageMagick, FFMPEG, ...) .

Comment: point taken, but to me it's just easier to implement with 2d array, plus compiler unrolls your loop so it has to execute less branches havin 2 pointers instead of one helps the compiler for longer unroll so less branches to be executed by the machine so faster code. Just my humble opinion :D

Comment: In a year, nobody is going to _care_ who edited what. @H2CO3 If you feel that an answer should be radically different in order to be correct, add your own. What you end up with is your content attributed to someone else, and that's a problem. I'm going to purge comments here tomorrow, please .. let's not have another rollback war.

Comment: @macrian, personally I would like to allocate once for whole image instead of 1081 times for 1080x1920 image. However, small memory chunks would have some benefits as well.

Comment: well this is why programming is not only a science but an arta, different artists make different artworks